# What's the difference in GET operations in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud Storage has several types of GET operations:

**Class A**

- GET Service
- GET Bucket (when listing objects in a bucket)

**Class B**

- GET Bucket (when retrieving bucket configuration)
- GET Object

Can anyone explain in "newbie's term" their differences?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "class A" and "class B" here. Could you give concrete examples?

Comment: @JonSkeet That's quite the point, it's Google who set those "classes"

Comment: So looking at the documentation, it looks like this is primarily about pricing. So presumably the Class A operations are more expensive internally. The classes just provide a simple way of bucketing quota/pricing - is that all you were asking about?

Comment: Not really, I need to know what exactly does each GET task do, well primarily just the GET service and GET object. Like for example, if I just want to display an image in my website and that image is hosted from GCS, what kind of GET is that?

Comment: Well that's just a matter of reading the API documentation. Follow all the links on the left in https://developers.google.com/storage/ (Start with "Getting Started" and then make sure you read the "Concepts and Techniques" in the Developer's Guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are terms specific to the XML API. You can see a full list of XML API methods and their names and meanings here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods

"GET Service" is the call to the XML API to list buckets owned by a project.

"GET Bucket (when listing objects)" is the call to list objects in a particular bucket.

"GET Bucket (when retrieving bucket configuration)" is the call to retrieve the metadata and configuratino of a particular bucket.

"GET Object" is the call to view an object's metadata or download its contents.